# Is there a way to continuously sync a shared onedrive with a custom made PHP/Mysql Portal

Tags: php, api, sharepoint, onedrive

Total noob in this field and a bit of a generic question, so please bear with me.
We got a sharepoint which automatically syncs with everyone's onedrive at work.
We also have a custom made portal (PHP) in which certain files are saved.
In order to access the files, one needs to log in to the custom made portal.

We are looking for ways to automatically sync whatever is saved on onedrive/sharepoint - in real time - with this portal. Our current PHP developer states that this is almost impossible/very hard to code as syncing only works well between Microsoft products.

Would this by any means be possible and feasible? We are just checking whether this would really be as hard as our developer claims it to be.

Cheers,

Matthew

Comment: Well you can use the Microsoft graph API to upload files to onedrive or sharepoint from anywhere

Comment: I'd ask the question why you rely on Microsoft products if they don't offer what you need ...